# SQL select posts that have similar tags

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mariadb

In my MariaDB I have a table called

"Posts" with

```
id, title, username_id, text, image_url, url
```

one called "tags" with

```
id, tag
```

and one called post_tags with

`id, post_id, tag_id`.

The thing I want to accomplish is to get 3 posts from the "Posts" table that have the most tags in common with the post that's currently shown on the page.

I'm stuck here not knowing where to start.

**EDIT**

```
Posts

id | username_id |   title   |    text     |       image_url      |           url

 1        1         example    example_text  localhost/image.jpg     localhost/first-post
 2        1         example1   example_text  localhost/image1.jpg    localhost/second-post
 3        1         example2   example_text  localhost/image2.jpg    localhost/third-post
 4        1         example4   example_text  localhost/image4.jpg    localhost/fourth-post
...      ...          ...          ...                ...                     ...
...      ...          ...          ...                ...                     ...


Tags

id | tag

 1   herbs
 2   flower
 3   rose

Post_tags

id | post_id | tag_id

 1      1        1
 2      1        2
 3      1        3
 4      2        1
 5      3        1
 6      3        2
 7      4        1
 8      4        2
 9      4        3
```

I'd like to return an array with `posts.title` and `posts.image_url` selecting the posts that have the most `post_tags.tag_id` in common with the current one.

As you can see, if we take post n. 1 as the selected post, post n. 4 has the most tags in common with it, post n.3 is in the second position and post n.2 is the third.

```
example4 | localhost/image4.jpg
example3 | localhost/image3.jpg
example2 | localhost/image2.jpg
```

I hope I made it clearer. Thank you.

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result. (As well formatted text.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.image_url, COUNT(*) as how_many_shared_tags
FROM posts p
JOIN post_tags pt ON pt.post_id = p.id
                 AND pt.tag_id IN(SELECT tag_id FROM post_tags WHERE post_id = 1)
WHERE p.id != 1
GROUP BY p.id, p.title, p.image_url
order by COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

As requested, explanation for query:

1. In order to find top 3 posts that share most tags with our "parent" post, we first need to get list of tags that "parent" has => `SELECT tag_id FROM post_tags WHERE post_id = 1`
2. Then find posts that have at least one of those tags by searching in table that holds both ID for posts and tags by adding condition `tag_id IN(LIST_OF_tag_id_FROM_SUB_SELECT_SHOWN_ABOVE)`.
3. Now we know what posts share at least one tag with "parent", so we can count how many tags they have actually in common and sort by it => `order by COUNT(*) DESC`
4. Because "parent" post also "shares" those tags and we don't want him in our result, we give additional condition excluding ID of our "parent" => `WHERE p.id != 1`
5. Finally we limit result set to 3 rows, because we want only top 3. `LIMIT 3`
6. Selecting count is not required, it is only to point out what it counts `COUNT(*) as how_many_common_tags`

Comment: Please explain how your query works so others may learn from it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this if it gives what you want to get. Then you may need to optimize query.

```
SELECT
t1.*
FROM posts t1,
(
    SELECT
    post_id
    FROM post_tags t2
    WHERE
    tag_id IN (SELECT tag_id FROM post_tags WHERE post_id = $CURRENT_POST_ID)
    AND NOT post_id = $CURRENT_POST_ID
    GROUP BY post_id
    ORDER BY COUNT(tag_id) DESC
    LIMIT 3
) t2
WHERE
t1.id = t2.post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you just the `post_id` values:

```
SELECT  x.post_id
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  b.post_id
            FROM  Post_tags a
            JOIN  Post_tags b USING(tag_id)
            WHERE  a.post_id = 1234
              AND  b.post_id != a.post_id
    ) x
    GROUP BY  x.post_id
    ORDER BY  COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT  3;
```

[*Tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) on designing a better mapping table (Post_tags).  That will give you the optimal indexes for that table.

To get more info on the 3 posts:

```
SELECT  p.*
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  x.post_id
            FROM  
            (
                SELECT  b.post_id
                    FROM  Post_tag a
                    JOIN  Post_tag b USING(tag_id)
                    WHERE  a.post_id = 1234
                      AND  b.post_id != a.post_id 
            ) AS x
            GROUP BY  x.post_id
            ORDER BY  COUNT(*) DESC
            LIMIT  3 
    ) AS y
    JOIN  Posts AS p  ON p.id = y.post_id;
```